# Storing an array in a database from a form where you can dynamically add fields (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I want to have a field in my registration form where users can enter a list of strings. They should be able to add as many strings to the list as they like by clicking a button. This list needs to be stored in the back-end and displayed on their profile page.

In my registration controller I'm hoping to have something along the lines of

```
//set user's list of strings to those from the registration form
$user->items = $request->items
```

And then on the user profile page I will display this list of items

```
<ul>
    <li>{{$user->item1}}</li>
    <li>{{$user->item2}}</li>
    <li>{{$user->item3}}</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: You can store as an array like $user->items = $request->items and then in the view {{$user->items['key1']}}, {{$user->items['key2]}}.  You can read about array casting here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
 <div id="dynamicInput">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></span>
 </div>
```

javascripts:

```
function addInput(divName)
{ 
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='items[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);    
}
```

storing in backend:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
 if(!empty($item))
  {     
    $add=new Item();   //Item is the model
    $add->name=$item;  //saving item to name column
    $add->save();       
  }
}
```

displaying:

```
$items=Item::where(['id'=>$id])->get(); 
foreach($items as $item)
{
       <li>{{$item->name}}</li>  // retreiving item from name column
}
```